# Can't install an update KB4284863. Reverting changes on reboot

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update, updates, windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

The system: Windows Server 2012 R2.

When I try to install KB4284863 it install successfully, but on reboot it says something like "Failure to configure updates. Reverting changes" The exact error might be different, since I have not English Windows.

Tried clean boot. In clean boot I disabled non-Microsoft services, but couldn't find the way to disable startup items. After clean boot the issue persist.

Tried Windows update troubleshooter and issue persist.

Tried deleting %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution folder and the issue persist.

Tried DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth - The restore operation completed successfully. The component store corruption was repaired, but the issue with update persist.

Comment: Are you installing from the network or from downloaded files on media such as USB? I've found downloading files from the MS catalog o be more likely to work. See http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4284863

Comment: I am installing from local drive. This is not an option.

Comment: copy the folder C:\windows\logs\CBS to desktop, zip the folder, upload the zip (onedrive, dropbox) and post a share link here. I'll look what is wrong.

Comment: I've uploaded the folder here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Agv-Sk4N45-QjnWgmY7QKXG1FkHKFFum Can I ask you to explain how you figure out the problem so that in future I can do it by myself?

Comment: I see error STATUS_XML_PARSE_ERROR (An error was encountered while processing an XML digital signature). I see WSUS tag. does the update install manually when you try the MSU?

Comment: I am trying to install update manually and the error is the same. Perhaps I can clear all logs and try installing again? In that way size of logs will be much smaller.

Comment: I deleted CBS folder, tried installing update again from local MSU, the update failed as usual and then I uploaded new CBS folder https://drive.google.com/open?id=1yfi6CbvLa7oju7nySxv4QieU7qx4A_gC

Comment: still the same issue and like in the old one I see this :"Startup: Failed while processing non-critical driver operations queue. [HRESULT = 0x80070490 - ERROR_NOT_FOUND]". Please also share the file C":\Windows\Inf\setupapi.dev.log"

Comment: I'v uploaded setupapi.dev.log here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1S-lBvFr_N50Fy6mKZckV685oijnmVp4j

Comment: **Failed to find driver update 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_iscsi.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.18470_none_2d88c8d8c79967be\iscsi.inf'** 6.3.9600.18470 should be December 2016 update. [Get the MSU](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/secu/2016/12/windows8.1-kb3205401-x64_90deeb4a6a70f1bb72a229bf8337f058ad0071a0.msu) and use [DISM](https://techjourney.net/how-to-install-cab-hotfix-or-update-with-dism/) to install the update without WUSA which would not install this old/replaced update

Comment: I've installed kb3205401, but the issue persist. On reboot the system says "Failure to configure updates. Reverting changes". I've uploaded the new CBS https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gFGykCZeXdhBj1njcmR1GTKStsO3EStO and the new setupapi log https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qvkv00gml0REYq-sxpZeZupcgaq0uutj

Comment: still the same. Get 2012 R2 ISO with November 2014 Update, [do repair Installation](https://www.eightforums.com/threads/repair-install-windows-8.26095/), now install the [April 2015 servicing stack update](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2015/04/windows8.1-kb3021910-x64_e291c0c339586e79c36ebfc0211678df91656c3d.msu), now the [july 2016 rollup](http://download.windowsupdate.com/c/msdownload/update/software/updt/2016/07/windows8.1-kb3172614-x64_e41365e643b98ab745c21dba17d1d3b6bb73cfcc.msu), reboot and now check for new WIndows updates.

Comment: I can always do repair install or even better - fresh installation. This is not a solution.

Comment: I have no idea. repair install keeps data/applications

Answer (score 0):

The workaround of the problem would be following:

1 Disable driver signature enforcement

2 Try to install driver with command `pnputil -a C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_iscsi.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.18470_none_2d88c8d8c79967be\iscsi.inf`

After that the update succeed.